# Using CTE to get a count into a variable, then trying to use same CTE to get the rows if variable is greater than 0

Tags: sql-server

What I'm  trying to do is this: use a variable, create a CTE, then use the count (*) function to return how many rows were returned from the CTE, if it's 0, just move on to the else; but I get an error: query looks like this

```
declare @number_of_rows as int;


with cte as (select a from b)
    SELECT @number_of_rows = count(*) FROM CTE
    print @number_of_rows

    if @number_of_rows = 0  print 'No Rows Found'
        ELSE --(execute a send mail function with the result set)

        select * from CTE -- I get an error here, can I not use the CTE again if I used it to store the variable ?
```

the error message is:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
>   Invalid object name 'CTE'.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without having to create a variable table inserting the rows, and using that? I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not turn this around a little bit and use EXISTS?

```
if exists (select a from b)
begin
    --send your email here
    select a from b
end
else
    print 'No Rows Found' --not sure print is the best idea here but whatever
```

Comment: this worked, the only issue, if I have a really long select statement, I have to write it twice.... no biggie as this seemed to work. What do you suggest instead of printing no  rows, basically I just don't want to do anything, maybe log an entry into an audit table.... or just end

Comment: The issue with using print is that the application and the user doesn't see it. You can do nothing and have the same result in the application. How are you sending your email? I bet we can do this without having to write a long query more than once.

Comment: I'm sending the email with sql mail... i'm not sure if there is a better way, now that I thought about it.... unless I throw the sql into a string variable and execute inside the sql_sendmail command .

Answer (score 0):

A CTE is married to its SELECT statement. Once that one statement (the SELECT) is fired, the CTE is no longer existing. It's all one statement.

The reason for this is that a CTE is just syntactic sugar for a subquery. Your first query rewritten is merely:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT a FROM b) as CTE;
```

Your CTE and this statement are 100% identical in every way from an execution standpoint.

What you are wanting is more akin to a view. Create the view, use it a couple of times, and drop it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
SELECT a FROM b
IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN
  print 'No Rows Found'
END
```